# DBCC SHRINKFILE 1 sproc for multiple databases

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have a need to execute DBCC SHRINKFILE for multiple db's within the same sproc.
I *could* create multiple sprocs so it runs within the given context, but I was curious if there were alternatives?

Answer (score 3):

Here is the code I use to perform this operation to shrink the logs on the databases beginning with 'MPS_' that are simple recovery.  This can be set as an SQL Execution Task maintenance plan and scheduled as appropriate.  The current code shrinks the log to 1 GB, which for us does a decent job of avoiding disk fragmentation.

Note that these are all volatile databases.  Never do this to production databases unless you really know what you're doing.  Also, *do not* just do this to every simple recovery model database.  Several of the system databases (`master`, for one) are simple recovery!

```
use [master]

set nocount on

declare @name sysname,
    @file_id int,
    @sqlcmd varchar(max)

DECLARE db_mps_simple_logs_cur CURSOR FOR
select d.name, mf.file_id
from sys.databases d
join sys.master_files mf
    on d.database_id = mf.database_id
where d.[name] like 'MPS_%'
    and d.recovery_model = 3 --simple only
    and mf.type = 1 --0 is data, 1 is log

open db_mps_simple_logs_cur
fetch next from db_mps_simple_logs_cur into @name, @file_id

while @@fetch_status = 0 begin

    set @sqlcmd = 'use ' + QUOTENAME(@name) + '; checkpoint; dbcc shrinkfile ( ' + cast(@file_id as varchar) + ', 1024 );'
    exec ( @sqlcmd )


    fetch next from db_mps_simple_logs_cur into @name, @file_id
end

close db_mps_simple_logs_cur
deallocate db_mps_simple_logs_cur
go
```

Here is a nice command that will show the current transaction log sized for simple recovery model databases so you can easily see the resuts:

```
select 
    d.database_id,
    d.name,
    d.recovery_model_desc,
    mf.name [file_name],
    mf.size * 8 / 1024 [size_in_mb],
    d.log_reuse_wait_desc
from sys.databases d
join sys.master_files mf
    on d.database_id = mf.database_id
where d.[name] like 'MPS_%'
    and d.recovery_model = 3 --simple only
    and mf.type = 1 --0 is data, 1 is log
order by mf.size desc
```

Answer (score -1):

```
EXEC sp_MSForEachDB 'USE ? DBCC SHRINKFILE (fileid, targetsize)'
```

The undocumented [sp_MSForEachDB](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=sp_MSForEachDB) is your friend here

Edit, after Raj's comment

```
EXEC sp_MSForEachDB '
    USE ?
    IF DB_NAME() IN (''DB1'', ''DB1'', ''DB1'')
       DBCC SHRINKFILE (fileid, targetsize)
     '
```

Edit

Note to downvoters, the dynamic SQL in the highest voted answer is basically a cut down sp_MSForEachDB

Comment: This will run for all databases on the server that the current account has permissions for.

Comment: Providing a worst practice solution, that may answer the question being asked but will cause problems later on, isn't really helpful to the community.  SQL Server isn't MS Access, shrinking is bad unless there is no way the space be required again, for example a 1TB database that gets a new monthly purging process implemented to groom database size, a one time shrink after the initial purge makes sense, but then it shouldn't be shrunk again if maintained.

Comment: Thanks for the input, you've made me re-think my approach:

"...for example a 1TB database that gets a new monthly purging process implemented to groom database size, a one time shrink after the initial purge makes sense, but then it shouldn't be shrunk again if maintained"

Answer (score -1):

Your best approach is, by far, to **never write a script that shrinks a database file**. From the million destructive things you can do with a database, shrinking it is right there in top 3. See [Auto-shrink – turn it OFF!](http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/PAUL/post/Auto-shrink-e28093-turn-it-OFF!.aspx).

Comment: Totally agree with Remus on this one.  The Log file is the most expensive of all files to grow since it has to be zeroed out during initialization and can't use instant file initialization.  SQL MVP Aaron Bertrand has a great blog post with lots of other references beyond Paul Randal's provided by Remus:  https://sqlblog.org/2009/07/27/oh-the-horror-please-stop-telling-people-they-should-shrink-their-log-files

Comment: That's certainly true for production databases, but it's easy to think of a situation it is appropriate. Our dev and test DBs are often instantiated from the prod DB, and then extensive queries are run. These dev/test DBs are sacrificial, so they're set to simple recovery. Even then, however, the logs grow (uselessly). We can set a max size, but then a large query can fail. There may be 10 such databases at any one time, and they are all considered volatile and are not backed up. We actually need to truncate and shrink the logs with `DBCC SHRINKFILE` weekly.

Comment: Another example of where this is useful: we restore a .bak daily from a provider that comes with a log that we don't need or want